# Cordova file transfer fails when Content-Length is not returned

Tags: ios, cordova, file-transfer, content-length

**iOS:** 
When a file is compressed and Content-Length is not returned by the server, a HEAD request is sent to get the Content-Length.

Unfortunately some firewalls and servers with compression set to 'force' compress the response and remove the Content-Length headers even on HEAD request (see http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX131488). 
This causes the plug-in to throw errors when trying to download a large number of files.

```
FileTransferError {
    code: 3,
    http_status: "",
    body: "",
    target: "path/to/file",
    source: "some_url"
}
```

Any suggestions how to solve the problem or disable the HEAD request without changing the plug-in?